# installing pango-1.36 on CentOS 5

Tags: cairo, centos5, pango

I'm trying to install pango-1.36 on a CentOS 5 sever where I do not have root access and therefore must install to a non-standard location. I have downloaded the source code, but when I attempt to run `./configure` I get the following error message:

```
checking which cairo font backends could be used... none
configure: Disabling cairo support
configure: error: *** Could not enable any backends.
*** Must have at least one backend to build Pango.
```

When I dig into the `config.log`, I see this:

```
configure:18613: $PKG_CONFIG --exists --print-errors "cairo-quartz-font >= $cairo_required"
Package cairo-quartz-font was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `cairo-quartz-font.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'cairo-quartz-font' found
configure:18616: $? = 1
configure:18631: checking which cairo font backends could be used
configure:18640: result: none
configure:18642: Disabling cairo support
configure:18793: error: *** Could not enable any backends.
*** Must have at least one backend to build Pango.
```

I'm not sure why pango is requiring `cairo-quartz-font` specifically. When I installed cairo I enabled Fontconfig, and that seemed to work:

```
# in cairo source directory
./configure --prefix=/some/custom/path --enable-fc
# lots of output, just showing summary
cairo (version 1.14.2 [release]) will be compiled with:

The following surface backends:
  Image:         yes (always builtin)
  Recording:     yes (always builtin)
  Observer:      yes (always builtin)
  Mime:          yes (always builtin)
  Tee:           no (disabled, use --enable-tee to enable)
  XML:           no (disabled, use --enable-xml to enable)
  Skia:          no (disabled, use --enable-skia to enable)
  Xlib:          yes
  Xlib Xrender:  yes
  Qt:            no (disabled, use --enable-qt to enable)
  Quartz:        no (requires CoreGraphics framework)
  Quartz-image:  no (disabled, use --enable-quartz-image to enable)
  XCB:           no (requires xcb >= 1.6 xcb-render >= 1.6 http://xcb.freedesktop.org)
  Win32:         no (requires a Win32 platform)
  OS2:           no (disabled, use --enable-os2 to enable)
  CairoScript:   yes
  PostScript:    yes
  PDF:           yes
  SVG:           yes
  OpenGL:        no (disabled, use --enable-gl to enable)
  OpenGL ES 2.0: no (disabled, use --enable-glesv2 to enable)
  BeOS:          no (disabled, use --enable-beos to enable)
  DirectFB:      no (disabled, use --enable-directfb to enable)
  OpenVG:        no (disabled, use --enable-vg to enable)
  DRM:           no (disabled, use --enable-drm to enable)
  Cogl:          no (disabled, use --enable-cogl to enable)

The following font backends:
  User:          yes (always builtin)
  FreeType:      yes
  Fontconfig:    yes
  Win32:         no (requires a Win32 platform)
  Quartz:        no (requires CoreGraphics framework)

The following functions:
  PNG functions:   yes
  GLX functions:   no (not required by any backend)
  WGL functions:   no (not required by any backend)
  EGL functions:   no (not required by any backend)
  X11-xcb functions: no (disabled, use --enable-xlib-xcb to enable)
  XCB-shm functions: no (requires --enable-xcb)

The following features and utilities:
  cairo-trace:                yes
  cairo-script-interpreter:   yes

And the following internal features:
  pthread:       yes
  gtk-doc:       no
  gcov support:  no
  symbol-lookup: no (requires bfd)
  test surfaces: no (disabled, use --enable-test-surfaces to enable)
  ps testing:    no (requires libspectre)
  pdf testing:   no (requires poppler-glib >= 0.17.4)
  svg testing:   no (requires librsvg-2.0 >= 2.35.0)
```

So it seems like cairo has a couple different font backends, including Fontconfig, enabled. Does pango need `cairo-quartz-font` specifically? Is there a way I can get it to use Fontconfig as well? Any help would be much appreciated and please let me know if there's additional information I can provide. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

For Debian and Debian derivatives including Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install libcairo2-dev
```

For Fedora:

```
sudo yum install cairo-devel
```

For openSUSE:

```
zypper install cairo-devel
```